# How do we prove the following containment relation regarding any set of functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Given a set of monotonically increasing positive mathematical functions over positive integers $S={f_0, f_1, f_2....}$. The value of each function is rounded to its nearest higher integer or $f_i(x)=ceil[f_i(x)]$.

Is it true that there always exists a function $f_a$ amongst these functions such that, for each remaining function $f_i$ in the set $S$, there exists a corresponding integer $x_i$ such that one of these constraints w.r.t. $f_a$ is true:

1. $f_a(x_i-1)\le f_i(x_i)\le f_a(x_i+1)$

In other words, the values of each remaining function $f_i$ for the some integer $x_i$ is sandwiched between two immediate values of $f_a$ (for the same $x_i)$.

2. $f_i(x)\leq f_a(x)$  for all $x$

In other words, $f_a$ is larger than or equal to $f_i$ for all integer values $x$.

I tried thinking how to prove it but I am struggling. Can someone please help with this.

Comment: Yes. I simply forgot that some functions might be strictly smaller than others for all integers so there would not be any 'crossing'.

Comment: a) "1 or 2" can be summarized (and made more explicit): For *some* integer $x_i,$ $f_a(x_i-1)\le f_i(x_i)\le f_a(x_i+1).$ b) Is this new "3" (for all $x_i$) an additional constraint? (i.e. you are looking for $a$ and $(x_i)$ satisfying 1+2+3) c) Isn't then "1" useless?

Comment: what I mean by that is there exists an $f_a$ such that each remaining function ($f_i$) satisfy one of the constraints.. hence the 'or'. If its unclear i request you to please update the language

Comment: $x_i$ is some integer that satisfies the constraint for $f_i$ and it would be different for each function $f_i$

Comment: That (last comment) was clear from the notations. But not "i request you to please update the language". Do you mean you want me to edit your post? I can't since I don't understand it, even with your comment before. Do you mean: "for each i, (1 or 2 or 3)"? or: "(for each i 1) or (for each i 2) or (for each i 3)"?

Comment: "for each remaining function $f_i$ in the set $S$, there exists an integer $x_i$ such that either (1) or (2) or (3) is true w.r.t. the selected $f_a$" hope i made it clear?

Comment: Note quite, since: a) in (3) there is no $x_i$, b) I don't understand why you do not replace "(1) or (2)" by $f_a(x_i-1)\le f_i(x_i)\le f_a(x_i+1)$ (incidentally, this would solve the problem that "*either* (1) or (2)" (disjunctive or) is not realized in case $f_i(x_i)=f_a(x_i)$).

Comment: @AnneBauval updated the Q. still struggling to solve/prove/disprove it though.

Comment: can someone please help with this?

Comment: c) Doesn't your formula $f_i(x)=ceil[f_i(x)]$ simply mean that $f_i$ is integer-valued? d) Anyway, even 2. alone is very often not satisfiable, i.e. a set of (positive, increasing, integer-valued) functions generally does not have a greatest element.